# Is there any plan to support the Firefox OS Web APIs in Intel XDK?

Tags: firefox, intel, firefox-os, html5-apps, intel-xdk

Intel XDK is a really promising tool for X-platform development.

Is Firefox OS considered as a supported platform for it?

Comment: Not sure! What sort of information did you come across when researching this?

Comment: Code completion for the new APIs, the integration of Firefox OS simulator to name a few. Is the question more accurate now?

Comment: Hey @daf182. Intel XDK kick some serious ass, but so does Firefox OS. Do you know it uses natively javascript to all the phone? So, if you just package your code that you made in the Intel XDK and publish it, it will run just as fine. The only thing that you may have to customize is your manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox OS is not currently supported by the Intel XDK. Could it be supported? Yes. Will it be supported? Not sure. As of this writing, our primary targets are those that support the Cordova API and the recently introduced Crosswalk runtime for Android. (The new Crosswalk target includes a Cordova 3.0 implementation.)

There are a lot of questions that need to be answered in order to support Firefox OS, mostly having to do with how do we support the Firefox OS API AND make your test/debug experience meaningful within the XDK. At the moment the only device APIs we can help you test and debug in a meaningful way are the Cordova and Intel XDK device APIs.

Check out our forum periodically for updates and improvements to the product.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, that was what I was interested in!